# Voting corrected does not match the number of downvotes

Tags: support

I received a series of downvotes in a short period of time (21:03 - 21:05) as shown in the image and generally the votes are reversed recovering my score but in this case it seems that not. Is that a bug or is it expected behavior?

The image shows that I received 7 downvotes losing 14 points but only recovered 8 points.

[image]

Comment: That's simple, only the four downvotes at 21:04 will've been corrected. The one at 21:03 and the two at 21:05 will've been missed because of the abysmal serial voting detection that SO do. This is normal

Comment: Feel free to raise a custom mod flag to investigate. I've had similar situations where votes around 10 seconds apart from each other weren't all detected as serial voting.

Comment: I’ve raised this with the CM team to have the remainder reverted, as it was very clearly targeted. In future, raise a custom moderator flag to ask us to investigate a possible targeted voting pattern when a series like this is not reverted automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is how voting reversal works. It only looks for patterns of 3 votes or more within a **single** minute. If the revenge votes are more scattered you need to ask CMs to invalidate it manually.

Comment: It’s also entirely possible they were issue by different users.  As somebody who has been a victim of serial downvotes that cross multiple communities, I feel for you, but my experience indicates it probably won’t be handled entirely.